# Android 6.0.1 - App details vs App permissions details vary

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have LeEco2. I am working on an app and I see something strange.
In my `App permissions` in `Location`, I see that location has been disabled for app but in `Location`->`Location Access`, it shows `Allowed`
In `App Management`, I see `Permissions` has no access to location

Answer (score 0):

`Location->Location Access` in the settings is to enable the GPS and the Permissions in your app settings is Permission for your app to use the Location Service.

You can have the following.

1. You can request for Location Permission and It can be given while the GPS is still turned off.
2. LOCATION SERVICE could be on and your app could have got the permission but then user can go back and turn off either of them.

I suggest you always check if GPS is ON before triggering location permission and before using it as well.